# Using Barcode Corners to Create CGRect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cgrect, avmetadataitem

I'm trying to draw a red rectangle over a detected barcode, using iOS 7's newest barcode api's. I've managed to pull in the bounds and corners, but I don't quite know how to take that information and apply it to my view.

In the viewDidLoad Method I define the view that I will use to overlay the barcode once found:

```
    //Initialize Laser View
    laserView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    laserView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    laserView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    laserView.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    [self.view addSubview:laserView];
```

In the didOutputMetadataObjects I prepare my laser view & pull in the barcode bounds and corners:

```
//Prepare Laser View's frame
CGRect laser = CGRectZero; 

laser = barcodeObject.bounds;
NSLog(@"Bounds: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(barcodeObject.bounds));
NSLog(@"Frame: %@", barcodeObject.corners);

//Update Laser
laserView.frame = laser;
```

In my latest run, for bounds I got: `{{7.0565414, 314.25}, {265.26062, 1.499999}}`
and for corners I got:

```
 (

    {
        X = "7.056541";
        Y = "314.25";
    },
        {
        X = "7.056541";
        Y = "315.75";
    },
        {
        X = "272.3172";
        Y = "315.75";
    },
        {
        X = "272.3172";
        Y = "314.25";
    }
)
```

I want to be able to tightly wrap a cgrect around a barcode. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Comment: What is your question? The bounds is a CGRect.

Comment: For example in a WWDC presentation, a barcode is scanned at an angle, and the overlay recognizes this skew, and tightly wraps around the barcode. The redlaser app does this as well. I've updated my answer with a photo

Comment: I see, in that case you are not using a rect (since that is always rectangular). Maybe use a UIBezierPath or CGPath?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to construct a `CGPath` or `UIBezierPath` path based on those corners and then draw the path.

- With the `CGPath` approach, create the path using `CGPathCreateMutable`. Create the path by using `CGPathMoveToPoint` to set the starting point and then using `CGPathAddLineToPoint` to move from there to each corner in turn. When you finish, you can use the path with a `CAShapeLayer`. Add that layer as a sub-layer in your view.
- With `UIBezierPath`, follow the same general approach as with `CGPath`. Use `moveToPoint:` to start and `addLineToPoint:` to draw the shape. Draw the path as usual (commonly in `drawRect` in a view).